# writing ghci session in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, haskell, command, haskell-stack

I am using the [queryparser](https://github.com/uber/queryparser) tool for parsing the queries .  I am using the stack ghci command to load the components and files of the tool into ghci,and will write the haskell commands.As soon as I use the "Stack ghci" it enters into an interactive mode to write the commands

I want to write a shell script and automate the process, and run the commands in programmatic mode.

The commands I am trying to run will be like

> demoTableLineage "INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar"
> demoJoins "SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar ON a=x AND b+c = y+z"

Do someone have idea to write them in a shell script and automate them in a programmatic way rather than the interactive way?

Comment: The shebang for Haskell is [**`runhaskell`**](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ghc/runhaskell.1.en.html), so you can put as first line of the script `#!/usr/bin/runhaskell`.

Comment: `stack script` might be interesting for you: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#the-script-interpreter-and-stack-script-command. Although I don't understand why you're not simply compiling a regular executable.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix system, you can create an executable file where the [*shebang* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), refers to the `runhaskell` executable. This is often located at `/usr/bin/runhaskell`, you thus can make a file with:

```
#!/usr/bin/runhaskell

main = print (2+2)
```

If you then make the file executable (`chmod +x myfile.hs`), then you can run this with:

```
$ ./myfile.hs
4
```